# Are supernatural encounters with Allah common in Islam?

Tags: allah, miracles, spirituality

In Islam, are theophanies possible? Can Allah visit a Muslim (or even a non-Muslim) to share a direct one-on-one message? Are testimonies of encounters with Allah common in Islam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. In Islam, there are no man-to-god physical/verbal encounters.
While yes we do believe God revealed verbal messages through prophets, it was never really Him coming down to earth as a human or verbally speaking to people.

The only person He showed Himself to and spoke one-on-one would be Prophet Moses.

Allah says in the Qur'an 7:143

> "When Moses came at the appointed time and his Lord spoke to him, he asked, “My Lord! Reveal Yourself to me so I may see You.” Allah answered, “You cannot see Me! But look at the mountain. If it remains firm in its place, only then will you see Me.” When his Lord appeared to the mountain, He leveled it to dust and Moses collapsed unconscious. When he recovered, he cried, “Glory be to You! I turn to You in repentance and I am the first of the believers.”

He won't show Himself to us humans nor reveal any more spiritual revelations to anyone else after the final prophets because they were the chosen ones.
The whole divine revelations were only left to the Prophets, not people.

Comment: I see. And what about angelic encounters? Are they possible in Islam?

Comment: Not since after Muhammad's time. Stuff involving angels and divine revelation are only held towards the Prophets, not average humans.

Comment: Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) did see Allah and he went to the arsh, without the help of Jibreel or the Burraq, said Jibreel (AS) on a point near the Sidrat Al Muntaha that no creation of Allah has gone above this point before and If I dear my wings will burn, and then a force made the Prophet (PBUH) ascend and further towards the arsh of Allah, that's also the point where we got the 5 salah, Some narrations say that Prophet Mohammad (PBUH) himself ascended towards the arsh but I haven't found any references to them and they might or might not be weak.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan He didn’t see his face though. All he saw was the Noor of Allah.